# Is there a way to count tokens in C?

Tags: c, token, delimiter, strtok

I'm using `strtok` to split a string into tokens. Does anyone know any function which actually counts the number of tokens?

I have a command string and I need to split it and pass the arguments to `execve()` .

Thanks!

**Edit**

`execve` takes arguments as `char**`, so I need to allocate an array of pointers. I don't know how many to allocate without knowing how many tokens are there.

Comment: `strtok()` and increment a counter?

Comment: And `realloc` should solve the problem of not knowing the size in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach would be to simply use `strtok` with a counter. However, that will modify the original string.

Another approach is to use `strchr` in a loop, like so:

```
int count = 0;
char *ptr = s;
while((ptr = strchr(ptr, ' ')) != NULL) {
    count++;
    ptr++;
}
```

If you have multiple delimiters, use `strpbrk`:

```
while((ptr = strpbrk(ptr, " \t")) != NULL) ...
```

Comment: strchr() gets cumbersome when there are multiple field delimiters,  for example punctuation.

Comment: You can use `strpbrk` in that case.

Comment: OK, I have amended my answer to include `strpbrk`. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Sorry to barge in like this but is this seemed like the best answer I've found. Is there a way to get the lengths of each segment between the delimiter. Thanks again for this answer. Cheers @nneonneo

Comment: You can just keep track of the previous value of `ptr` and take the difference between the two - the pointers point to different parts of the same string.

Answer (score 4):

As number of tokens is nothing but one more than the frequency of occurrence of the delimiter used. So your question boils down to find no. of times of occurrence of a character in a string

say the delimiter used in strtok function in c is ' '

```
int count =0,i;
char str[20] = "some string here";

for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){
    if(str[i] == ' ')
        count++;
}
```

No. of tokens would be same as count+1

Comment: Does the job but gets cumbersome if more than one delimiter is allowed.

Comment: I guess we can use the same procedure and should take care of the corner cases

Comment: This would count two spaces in a row as two separate word-separators. Doesn't `strtok()` treat consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version based on `strtok` which does not modify the original string, but a temporal copy of it. This version works for any combination of tabs and space characters used as tokens separators. The function is

```
unsigned long int getNofTokens(const char* string){
  char* stringCopy;
  unsigned long int stringLength;
  unsigned long int count = 0;

  stringLength = (unsigned)strlen(string);
  stringCopy = malloc((stringLength+1)*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(stringCopy,string);

  if( strtok(stringCopy, " \t") != NULL){
    count++;
    while( strtok(NULL," \t") != NULL )
        count++;
  }

  free(stringCopy);
  return count;
}
```

A function call could be

```
char stringExample[]=" wordA 25.4 \t 5.6e-3\t\twordB 4.5e005\t ";
printf("number of elements in stringExample is %lu",getNofTokens(stringExample));
```

Output is

```
number of elements in stringExample is 5
```