# Counting the amount of string tokens in C

Tags: c, parameters, terminal, token, strtok

I need to make a program that will emulate the terminal of Linux. Since some system calls requires 1,2 or more arguments, I want to make sure that the number of parameters given are correct. I'm using `strtok()` to separate the call name from the arguments, but I need to know how many tokens `strtok()` created to compare it.

Here's and example code:

```
char *comand = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
char *token;
char *path1 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
char *path2= (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);



    fgets(comand, 100, stdin);

    printf( "\nYou entered: %s \n", comand);

    token = strtok(comand ," ");

    //Check the number of tokens and add a condition in each IF to match

    if (strcmp("ls",token) == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path1,token);

    }
    else if (strcmp("cat",token) == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path1,token);

    }
    else if (strcmp("cp",token) == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path1,token);
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path2,token);

    }
    else if (strcmp("mv",token) == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path1,token);
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path2,token);    

    }
    else if (strcmp("find",token) == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path1,token);

    }
    else if (strcmp("rm",token) == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path1,token);

    }
    else if (strcmp("mkdir",token) == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path1,token);
    }
    else if (strcmp("rmdir",token) == 0) {
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
        strcpy(path1,token);
    }
    else if (strcmp("quit",token) == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }
    else print("Number of parameters do not match);
```

Comment: "System calls"? From the console?

Comment: No, the "System calls" of this "Terminal" are procedures made in language C, not the Unix ones. If the command is "ls", then I would call a procedure named "commLs" or something like that, and pass it the tokens.

Comment: You might also want to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078926/is-there-a-way-to-count-tokens-in-c

Comment: What will you do about quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

the only thing `strtok()` does is look for the next occurance of the delimiter and overwrite that character with a `\0` and return the pointer with the offset added. the pointer is kept in a static variable that's why a subsequent call to it with a NULL for the `char *` will perform it on the last string used from the offset that the last delimiter was found.

this page has a very nice example:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

If you only want to count the arguments it would be easier to use `strchr()`, this function searches for a character and returns a pointer to its location. you could use it like this.

```
unsigned int i = 0;
char *temp = token;
while ( (temp = strchr(temp, '') != NULL) ) {
    ++i;
}
```

this has the added benefit of not modifying your original char array while `strtok()` does!

I would handle this within the functions you create for each command.

you pass all options to the function and there you parse it. either with `strtok()` or whatever else you want to use.

This keeps it nice and clean within the sub-routines and you will always know what to expect.

```
if (strcmp("ls",token) == 0) {
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
    strcpy(path1,token);      // I would maybe change the path variable name to args
    ret = lscmd(path1);
    if (ret == -1) {
         // invalid input detected
    }  
}
```

then you would have a ls function

```
int lsdcmd(char *args) {
    // parse args for argumants you are looking for, return -1 if it fails

    // do whatever you want to do.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the arguments using strtok this way:

Example:

```
const char* delimiter = ",";
char* tokens[MAX_NUM_OF_ARGS];

unsigned int index = 0;
char* temp = strtok(buff,delimiter);
while (temp!=NULL){
    if(index<MAX_NUM_OF_ARGS){
        tokens[index]=temp;
    }
    index++;
    temp = strtok(NULL,delimiter);
}
```

Then later you can iterate through the array of pointers (tokens) and compare them...